# How to round timestamp to nearest day with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

How can I round a timestamp to the nearest day in postgresql.
I have tried using function date_trunc('day', d_date::timestamp) but I get that is always staying in the same day.

**Example 1:**

```
date_trunc('day' , '1967-12-03 23:00:00')

Result:

1967-12-03 00:00:00.000000

Expected:

1967-12-04 00:00:00.000000
```

**Example 2:** (This one works fine)

```
date_trunc('day' , '1967-12-03 00:00:00')

Result:

1967-12-03 00:00:00.000000

Expected:

1967-12-03 00:00:00.000000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add 12 hours to the timestamp and then do the truncation that you're doing already.

Something like...

```
date_trunc('day' , timestamp '1967-12-03 23:00:00' + interval '12 hours')
```

Comment: @S-Man I believe it does work for times less than 12:00:00. 1967-12-03 08:00:00 gives 1967-12-03 22:00:00 as an answer that is truncated to 1967-12-03 00:00:00 which is the original date rounded down.

Comment: Sry, yes my fault.